# Kotlin not loading web page in web view

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to load a webpage into my webview and with javascript fill in a form and click a button, but nothing is happening. Any clue why?

Kotlin:

```
val webViewLogin = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webViewLogin)
        webViewLogin.loadUrl("https://mail.metropolitan.ac.rs/?loginOp=logout")
        webViewLogin.settings.javaScriptEnabled
        webViewLogin.settings.domStorageEnabled

        val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {

            webViewLogin.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    // Page loading started
                    // Do something
                    println("Page loading...")
                }

                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                    // Page loading finished

                    webViewLogin.loadUrl(
                        "javascript:(function() { " +
                                "document.getElementById('username').value = 'myUsername'; null " +
                                "document.getElementById('password').value = 'myPassword' null;" +
                                "document.getElementsByClassName('ZLoginButton DwtButton').click()" +
                                "})()"
                    )
                    println(webViewLogin.title.toString())
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the debug log?

Comment: @kPieczonka none, I have no clue to what is wrong

Comment: Thats ok.
First thing you should consider is looking at the error logs inside Android Studio. 
Typically when you start the app there is a log showing at the bottom of your screen. When the app is trying to start the webview it should write out the error that is causing it to fail. Please find that and send over the content of the error and ill try my best to help you resolve